# Android Increasing View's Layout Weight Decreases Actual Width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-layout-weight

I've tried to track down what's going wrong here, and I'm coming up with nothing.  If i change my layout weight from 1 to 2, on the first view in my horizontal linear layout, the resulting width actually decreases.  Here is the code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="7">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/filterButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="filter"></TextView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:ems="14"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="left">
        </AutoCompleteTextView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/close"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/listButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/list"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is what my action bar looks like with the TextView's layout weight set to 1.

[image]

You can see I'm already getting some overflow on the right element.  It's getting bumped off screen.  Here is what it looks like with the TextView's weight set to 2.

[image]

Which is odd because the TextView has actually decreased in size.  Here is the action bar without the TextView.  The sizes are behaving well here.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I face this most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks similar to problem i have sometimes.
For layout with weight 7 it would give space like that [[..2..][.5]].
Like in your example making weight smaller actually give more space for layout.
Try to change background color of the middle layout to have better grasp what space exacly is given to your layouts.
Unlucky on my computer your code works normally so I can't help more than that.